# JS возвращает undefined | Python | Eel

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, массивы, eel

Не могу решить проблему. Написал программу, вот ее краткое описание:
Приложение, логика которого написана на **python**, а интерфейс отображается с использованием **HTML** и **CSS**. В python импортирован модуль **eel**. В питоне прописана функция, возвращающая массив. В JS создается переменная, принимающая итог функции, и после результат записывается в классы HTML. Вот как это выглядит:

- **Код python**

  ```
   import eel
   import datetime
   import sys


   eel.init("web")

   isoWD = datetime.datetime.today().isoweekday()

   @eel.expose
   def some_func():
       if isoWD == 1:
           result = ['элементы', 'массива', 'элементы', 'массива', 'элементы', 'массива']

       elif isoWD == 2:
           result = ['элементы', 'массива', 'элементы', 'массива', 'элементы', 'массива']

       elif isoWD == 3:
           result = ['элементы', 'массива', 'элементы', 'массива', 'элементы', 'массива']

       elif isoWD == 4:
           result = ['элементы', 'массива', 'элементы', 'массива', 'элементы', 'массива']

       elif isoWD == 5:
           result = ['элементы', 'массива', 'элементы', 'массива', 'элементы', 'массива']

       elif isoWD == 6:
           result = ['элементы', 'массива', 'элементы', 'массива', 'элементы', 'массива']

       elif isoWD == 7:
           sys.exit()

       return result


   eel.start("main.html", size=(325, 450))
  ```
- **Код HTML**

  ```
   <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="block">
           <div class="block__num"><p>(1)</p></div>
           <div class="block__les"></div>
           <div class="block__time">09.00 - 09.30</div>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
           <div class="block__num"><p>(2)</p></div>
           <div class="block__les"></div>
           <div class="block__time">09.40 - 10.10</div>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
           <div class="block__num"><p>(3)</p></div>
           <div class="block__les"></div>
           <div class="block__time">10.20 - 10.50</div>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
           <div class="block__num"><p>(4)</p></div>
           <div class="block__les"></div>
           <div class="block__time">11.00 - 11.30</div>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
           <div class="block__num"><p>(5)</p></div>
           <div class="block__les"></div>
           <div class="block__time">11.40 - 12.10</div>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
           <div class="block__num"><p>(6)</p></div>
           <div class="block__les"></div>
           <div class="block__time">12.20 - 12.50</div>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
           <div class="block__num"><p>(7)</p></div>
           <div class="block__les"></div>
           <div class="block__time">13.00 - 13.30</div>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
           <div class="block__num"><p>(8)</p></div>
           <div class="block__les"></div>
           <div class="block__time">13.40 - 14.10</div>
        </div> 
   </div> 

   <script type="text/javascript" src="/eel.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function display() {
           var res = eel.some_func();
           for (var i = 0; i <= 'block__les'.length; i++) {
               document.getElementsByClassName('block__les')[i].innerHTML = res[i];
           }
       }
       display();
   </script>
  ```

Программа выводит следующее:

[image: Output]

Comment: джс получает парильно функцию с бека ```eel.some_func();```?

Comment: @ВиталийБриль Здесь всё верно, я действовал согласно официальной документации eel - https://pypi.org/project/Eel/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 function display() {
     var res = eel.some_func();
     var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName('block__les');
     console.log(blocks.length, res); // - ?
     for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
         blocks[i].textContent = res[i];
     }
 }
 display();
```

Comment: Теперь элементы не определяются как undefined, однако дивы всё равно не заполняются текстом, они остаются пустыми

Comment: @C9F `console.log(blocks.length, res);` - что в консоли браузера?